# Parsing Yahoo Rss Feeds for android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss, yahoo

Can someone help me for parsing the Yahoo RSS Feeds, from the URL [Yahoo Feed](http://news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment)

I am able to call and fetch URL. I have the response in string. I would like to parse it and show the feeds in list. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

you should use xmlpullparser or sax parser or dom parser for xml rss feeds parsing
try this example

```
  try {
        URL url = new URL("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

            /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
             * However, we should take in consideration that the rss feed name also is enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
             * As we know, every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title>...."
             * so we should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
             * and take in consideration only "<title>" tag which is a child of "<item>"
             *
             * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable.
             */
        boolean insideItem = false;

            // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                }
            }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem=false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
       try {
           return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot...!!! It works. I am able to extract all the data item. But I also need to extract the attribute of "media:content" as "url" for showing the pic for news. Little more help plz... :)